# Jira Work Log Report

Tags: jira

I'm trying to figure out a way to generate a report that show the work logged by me (another specified user) where it shows the time and also comments about the work logged, associated ticket, epic, etc. I've found a couple ways that are close, but not really what I need. Is there a way to do this easily without additional plug-ins, etc?

On a summary level, I just want to see all the work I logged today with the specifics I entered for the tasks performed (not just time - what results did I produce today!).

Answer (score 2):

This may be too late to answer, but may help others who are searching for the solution with same issue.

One of the free option available is to use the browser extension named Jira Assistant available in below url. No need of adding this plugin to jira. You can just have it in your browser. This extension has lot more useful features which not only helps to generate report, but also help to log your work on daily basis with notifications, calendar integrations and lot more cool features which helps both managers and team members in their daily activity:

For Chrome users: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jira-assistant/momjbjbjpbcbnepbgkkiaofkgimihbii?src=sof

For Firefox users: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jira-assistant/

Comment: It is the only way to view spent time. Shame for Jira.

Answer (score 0):

Even free-er! :

I accept this doesn't completely answer the question but I feel it will be a good-enough base to work from to meet your exact spec, particularly as new visitors to this old question might be after something slightly different anyway.

Much overlooked in bolting on functionality is the use of javascript bookmarklets.  Make a bookmark in chrome - any bookmark! Then edit it and change the name to "Jira Worklog" and the url to:

```
javascript:var pswl=$(".zzzpswl"); if (pswl.length>0){pswl.remove();}else{$(".issuerow").each(function(){ var row=$(this);var issId=$(this).attr("rel"); jQuery.ajax({url:"/rest/api/2/issue/"+issId,success:function(result){console.log(result);result.fields.worklog.worklogs.forEach(function(wl) {var startParts=(new Date(wl.started)).toDateString().split(" ");var newRow="<tr class='zzzpswl'><td></td><td></td><td colspan=100>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+wl.author.displayName+": <b>"+wl.timeSpent+"</b> on <b>"+startParts[0]+" "+startParts[2]+"-"+startParts[1]+"-"+startParts[3]+"</b>"+(wl.comment?" : "+wl.comment:"")+"</td></tr>";row.after(newRow);});}});});}
```

If you then view any search results page in Jira and hit the bookmark, it will add rows under each jira in the search result showing the worklog (including comment) for that item.